# Why does it raise "syntax error"？

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I'm using Backbone.js+jQuery+underscore.js (libraries are completely loaded successfully), here're my codes:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="jslib/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jslib/underscore.js"></script>
    <script src="jslib/backbone.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            var Person = Backbone.Model.extend(
            {
                default:
                {
                    name: "",
                    age: 0
                }
            });

            var PeopleList = Backbone.Collection.extend(
            {
                model: Person
            });

            var peoplelist = new PeopleList();

            for (var i = 1; i < 11; ++i) {
                var p = new Person();
                p.set("name", "Name" + i);
                p.set("age", parseInt(Math.random() * 50));
                peoplelist.add(p);
            }

            var myView = Backbone.View.extend(
            {
                el: "#mydiv",
                template: "",
                render: function () {
                    for (var i = 0; i < peoplelist.length; ++i) {
                        $(this.el).html(this.template(peoplelist.at(i).toJSON()));
                    }
                },
                constructor: function () {
                    var htmltext = $("#templaterow").html();
                    this.template = _.template(htmltext);
                    this.render();
                }
            });

            var mv = new myView();
        })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mydiv">
        <table>
            <script type="text/template" id="templaterow">
                <tr>
                    <td><%= name></td>
                    <td><%= age%></td>
                </tr>
            </script>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now my question is when running in IE, it shows me this:
[image]

So, what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arent you missing closing `%` in `<td><%= name></td>`? Change that to

```
<td><%= name %></td>
```